# 2sxc - Calculated Fields implementation

Tags: 2sxc

Can I make calculated fields in 2sxc?
Something like url path, but to use more fields and some additional logic?
Is the only way to do this custom property editor?

I also know for this video about url-path:
http://2sxc.org/en/Docs/Feature/feature/8305

But don't know where are sources for this editor that I can copy it and modify for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom input type - see http://2sxc.org/en/Blog/post/custom-input-type-advanced-dynamic-data

the code for the url-path is here: https://github.com/2sic/eav-ui/blob/master/src/edit/fields/string/string-url-path.js